# Handle remote notifications when phone is locked/app not running

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using a combination of Firebase and Batch for a chat like application.

When a push notification is received the app should be able to perform some tasks based on the data received in the notification.

From my understanding this can *only* be done in app states `suspended` -> `active` and not `terminated`.

I have it working when the app is in the foreground and also when closing the app via home button.

Should the device be locked however, `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is never called. At least not until the user interacts with the notification from notification center.

Is this correct? Can no work be done on a remote notification if the device is locked?

I have all the appropriate entitlements and `"content-available":1` set correctly.

Is there another way that I can wake the app up from a notification and do a few background tasks? I also tried using [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) but had the same issue with nothing happening while the device was locked.

Comment: If you have a VoIP app then you can use PushKit, but either way it is best practice for your app to check for new content each time it is launched as push notifications are not guaranteed

Comment: Yeah I understand how that's best practice but these are fairly time sensitive. They're not important enough to HAVE to be triggered, but by the time the user opens the app they'll no longer be relevant. Are you saying PushKit should be able to do what I'm after? Since it's a chat app, VoIP might fit in well.

Comment: Just checked the docs for VoIP. @Paulw11 if you can fill out an answer, would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Paulw11 VoiP worked for me.